# ActionScript 3 md5-bin from string

Tags: php, actionscript-3, nginx, base64, md5

How can I get a similar procedure in AS3

```
$hash = md5('string', true);.
$hash = strtr(base64_encode($hash), '+/', '-_');.
echo "$hash \n";
```

rezult:**tFz_4ITdPSDZKL7oXnsPIQ==**

I can get md5-bin from a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a third party library.

I suggest [as3crypto](http://code.google.com/p/as3crypto/)

And here is an [EXAMPLE](http://code.google.com/p/as3crypto/source/browse/trunk/as3crypto/src/com/hurlant/crypto/tests/MD5Test.as?r=14)

Answer (score 0):

as3crypto return a md5 hash-string 32 simbols, I need raw output 16 simbols.
I need to make nginx secure link 
http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpSecureLinkModule#Example_usage:

$md5 = base64_encode(md5($secret . $path . $expire, true)); **// Using binary hashing.**

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED:

```
var md5_hash:String = MD5.hash('string');
var hash:String = Base64.encodeByteArray(Hex.toArray(md5_hash));
```